# How to add progress bar over third party activity

Tags: android

I'm using a third party cropping activity and when I hit the crop button there is no progress bar and it feels the app is stuck.
I was wondering if there is a way to add a progress bar although it's a third party activity and i don't have access to the code.

Third party project on github: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: don't you get the image in your activity onActivityResult(...) method after you click crop button???

Comment: I'm not talking about the image, I want to start a progress bar as soon as I press the crop button and dismiss it when the image has been updated. Starting a progress bar when I receive the image in onActivityResult is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I could tell by debugging that the progress bar is starting but I don't see it and by the time my app finishes processing the image the progress bar should be closed.
So I sent the image processing to be handled in a different thread and on the UI thread in `onActivityResult` I started the progress bar, added some code to identify when the image processing was done and then stopped the progress bar.

Previously the processing was handled on the main thread and it had the app stuck on a black screen and although the progress bar did start I couldn't see it because the UI was stuck handling the image processing.
I have worked with several threads before but it didn't occur to me at the time that this is the problem.

hope this would be useful to some of you.